# table or view doesn't exist error

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-xe

I'm using Oracle XE, in which i was making my own custom trigger. For that, I've made two tables **INSERTED** and **ORDER_INFO** in the **SYSTEM** schema, both have the same column name ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE. In my scenario, client will be placing his/her order then, order information will be stored into **INSERTED** table, then by using this trigger, it'll insert into another table **ORDER_INFO** after satisfying the condition.

this is what i got till now,

```
CREATE TRIGGER tri_check
   AFTER INSERT ON inserted FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF :new.order_date < (SYSDATE + 2)
   THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now');
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO orders_info (order_id, order_date)
      VALUES (:new.order_id, :new.order_date);
   END IF;
END;
```

While executing the above query, i'm getting this error

```
ERROR at line 7: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
5.    IF :new.order_date < (SYSDATE + 2)
6.    THEN
7.        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now');
8.    ELSE
9.       INSERT INTO orders_info (order_id, order_date)
```

Need Help !!

Comment: Just as a point to learn from you should never add your objects/tables/etc to the SYSTEM schema. It's like sticking your fingers in a running engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you do

`INSERT INTO orders_info`

instead of

`INSERT INTO ORDER_INFO`